# I want apply one image effect to other image effect in android

Tags: java, android

I have one image in android resource folder and second image is capturing from camera using application. 
Now I want to get effect of first image(from android resource folder) and want to apply same effect on captured image by camera in android.

Approach Applied :
First I find RGB from first image for one Pixel and again find RGB from second image for One Pixel, calculating difference between both RGB values and difference applied for second RBG values for all pixels.
Output Image is in Gray Color.

```
private void gettingRGBDifference(){

    Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.lady);
    int width=(bmp.getWidth()*88/100);
    int height=(bmp.getHeight()*85/100);
    Bitmap resizedBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp,1220,560, width-1220, height - 560);
    cropCircleImageView.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);

    int colour = resizedBitmap.getPixel(160, 160);

    int red = Color.red(colour);
    int blue = Color.blue(colour);
    int green = Color.green(colour);
    int alpha = Color.alpha(colour);
    byte[] rgbArray;

    Bitmap circleImageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.circle);

    int colour1 = circleImageBitmap.getPixel(150, 150);

    int red1 = Color.red(colour1);
    int blue1 = Color.blue(colour1);
    int green1 = Color.green(colour1);
    int alpha1 = Color.alpha(colour1);


    redDifference = red - red1;
    blueDifference = blue - blue1;
    greenDifference = green - green1;

}
```

Can anyone correct my approach?

Comment: do you want to draw one image on top of other image?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko, Yes

Comment: @Andreas I have edited my question, If you need more info, Please suggest

Comment: Ok, so according to your code you don't want to draw one image on top of another. Now it is not clear what is a problem.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko in code I am getting RGB color code difference only.

Comment: that does not sound like a problem

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko using above approach I am getting wrong effect. Can possible to make both image effect same ?

Comment: It is still not clear which effect you want